# Парсер комментариев из поста в telegram

Tags: python, pycharm, telegram

Всем привет, решил провести небольшое исследование и для этого необходимо вытащить комментарии (порядка 500 тысяч) из отдельного поста в чужом открытом telegram канале.
Все, что пытаюсь найти собирает только сами посты (это можно сделать и через сам telegram).
Нашел один проект на github (https://github.com/PeterWalchhofer/Telescrape) но он крайне массивный и через pycharm запустить так и не удалось.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью библиотеки Telethon ([документация](https://docs.telethon.dev))

Для примера получение комментариев для поста https://t.me/mudak/57071 будет выглядеть так:

```py
async for message in client.iter_messages('mudak', reply_to=57071, reverse=True):
    if isinstance(message.sender, types.User):
        print(message.date, message.sender.first_name, ':', message.text)
    else:
        print(message.date, message.sender.title, ':', message.text)
```

Результат:

```
2021-12-22 10:20:23+00:00 Олег : 1
2021-12-22 10:20:58+00:00 Mod : шиза 
2021-12-22 10:21:22+00:00 Ⓜ️ɪꜱꜱ **** : Уахахахахах жиза)) ещё падаю как будто с обрыва и в страхе просыпаюсь))
2021-12-22 10:21:43+00:00 HOLYWEED : в начале показывают, обычной перелет компанией Ютейр
2021-12-22 10:23:03+00:00 Маша : Что может быть лучше английского у меня на канале?
2021-12-22 10:26:00+00:00 _zee_ : жиза*
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень выручили))) Осталось допилить вывод этих данных в csv, но с этим уже сам постараюсь разобраться)))